How do I import a module with ".js" in its name without triggering a TypeError?
When I run my project locally, it works fine. But when I deploy it to AWS Amplify, it shows an error from the browser's console:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "hls.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

But hls.js is the name of the  npm module. video.js another npm module also triggers this error.
I tried using:
import { Hls } from 'hls.js';

But it outputs the same error.
I tried using CDN links to import hls.js, but it resulted in this error:

SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@1' does not provide an export named 'default'

EDIT: Additional information:
The script is added to the HTML file with
<script type="module" src="src/api/script.mjs"></script>

I tried importing it with require but I think it doesn't work since the file extension is .mjs.
I upload it to GitHub with git, and it deploys and builds automatically in AWS with npm run build.

you can only import from URLs, and hls.js is not a URL (on its own). The error is telling you how to fix it: add a ./ in front if it's an import from the same dir, or some other prefix that turns it into a real URL.

@Phil I am uploading it to GItHub and it auto-deploys on AWS Amplify.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans When I install it using npm install hls.js, the module/package is inside a folder named node_modules with a folder named hls.js. I am new to web development, especially in JavaScript, so I apologize for any misunderstandings I might get.

What are the NodeJS versions you are using locally and in production? You should use the same version. Try to upgrade the one used in production to be the same version as your local version. I’ll write an answer to show where this error comes from.

@ChukwujiobiCanon I tried changing the AWS server NodeJS version to v20.1.0-the same as what I have locally with this guide, but it still raises the same original error.

Again, where exactly are you seeing this error? Is it generated as part of a build process (Github Action) or do you see it somewhere on the AWS side? Please [edit] your question to include details.

One workaround you could try is to alias the hls.js dependency under a different name, eg hls-js

@Phil The error is present in the browser's console when I try to inspect it.

I don't understand your build or deployment process. Since you're installing Node dependencies, I assumed you were using a bundler of some sort but perhaps that's not the case. Please [edit] your question to provide details. How is this app constructed? If it's not bundled and you're just using <script type="module">, how exactly are node_modules packages served? Are you using an importmap?

@Phil Apologies for the confusion due to my lack of knowledge in this language. I'll add what I know: The script is added to the HTML file with <script type="module" src="src/api/script.mjs"></script>.  I tried importing it with require but I think it doesn't work since the file extension is .mjs. I upload it to GitHub with git, and it deploys and builds automatically in AWS with npm run build. I am quite unfamiliar with importmap and bundlers.

You don't seem to be grasping the "[edit] your question" requests. The comments are not the place for details. Please also include your package.json "scripts" section

reading through https://www.npmjs.com/package/hls.js, this package it looks like what you really want to do is just use it from their CDN link and simply add the script tag to your HTML and then use the global object that exposes. If you need to import it using ESM, and that doesn't work, ask the people who maintain it to add an example of how to use it in ESM context to the readme over on their issue tracker or discussion board.

I can assume that you are using Vite, they have slightly different build pipelines in development and production.
Anyway, when I tried to pull hls.js from the package and load them separately, for example:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>

I had the same problem when building it for production. The solution for me was to tell Rollup (used for production builds) that this dependency should be looked up as external, something like:
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        externalGlobals({
          'hls.js': 'Hls'
        }),
      ],
    }

where externalGlobals is the rollup-plugin-external-globals package that I added in addition to vite-plugin-external.
